# в safari не корректно отображается компонент Сounter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsbyjs

Всем доброго времени, подскажите пожалуйста, я еще пока учусь, и сложно разобраться что делаю не так, разрабатываю на Gatsby, прописала каунтер, он хорошо работает в хроме, но в сафари пишет NAN
вот скрин с хрома
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот мой компонент

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const startDate = moment('01-01-2022');

class MainCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: this.props.startCount + moment().diff(startDate, 'hours'),
    };

    this.interval = null;
  }

  setCount = () => {
    const updatedCount =
      this.props.startCount + moment().diff(startDate, 'hours');

    if (this.state.count < updatedCount) {
      this.setState({ count: updatedCount });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.setCount, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <span className="main-counter__value">{this.state.count}</span>;
  }
}

MainCounter.propTypes = {
  defaultCount: PropTypes.number,
};`введите сюда код`

export default MainCounter;
```

[это в хром](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rjc6.png)

[image: это safari]

Буду очень благодарна за помощь! и конечно шлю вам 100кратный позитифф в карму!

Answer (score 1):

нашла ошибку))
неверно указала формат даты

```
const startDate = moment('01-01-2022');
```

```
const startDate = moment('2022-01-01');
```